# Do all carmichael numbers contain a 1 or a 6?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have only seen a short list but they all contain a 1 or a 6 somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No](http://www.kobepharma-u.ac.jp/~math/notes/note02.html). $278545$ is a Carmichael number.